# How to dedupe and merge database records from different sources using java?

Tags: java, lucene, spring-batch

I have two tables from two different database. I have to retrieve them and remove the records which are present in both the tables and store the remaining into another table.

Both the table has one common column to find out whether it is duplicate or not.

Currently we are retrieving the records from both the tables and using java.util.set to remove the duplicates and then we are inserting the records. If the record size is small, this is good, but i want to find out more optimized solution for huge records.

I thought of sorting the records from two tables and do de-dupe. But this will not work for huge records, until i load them all into memory and compare. If the record is huge, it is impossible. If i load in 1000s, there could be chances some record gets loose in edge case.

Is [Duke de-dupe](https://github.com/larsga/Duke/wiki) necessary for this? will it work?

Any other idea?

Comment: If you can sort within your DB query, you should only need to load one record from each dataset into memory at a time.  [Something like this](http://www.algolist.net/Algorithms/Merge/Sorted_arrays)...

Comment: right, but I want to insert the final data in a small chunk. Merge sort will work if I am inserting the final data in a single shot. If I want to do small chunks, it is not possible i believe